# Positive codimension of locus of singular points in semi-algebraic varieties

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-topology, semialgebraic-geometry

I am reading the paper  [A geometric proof of the existence of Whitney stratifications](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0010144.pdf). Theorem 1 states

> Theorem 1. For any semivariety $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ (or $\mathbb{C}^m$) there is an a- (resp. b-) regular stratification.

The first paragraph in proof of Theorem 1 says:

"A semivariety $V$ has well-defined dimension, say $d \leq m$. Denote
by $V_{reg}$ the set of points, where $V$ is locally a real (or complex) analytic submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^m$ (or $\mathbb{C}^m$) of dimension $d$. $V_{reg}$ is a semivariety, moreover, $V_{sing} = V \setminus V_{reg}$ is a semivariety of positive codimension in $V$ , i.e., $\dim V_{sing} < \dim V$."

My question is: why $V_{sing}$ is a semivariety of positive codimension in $V$?

Comment: Did you check the references listed directly after the quote? The paper refers to Lojasiewicz's *Ensemble Semi-Analytiques*, [available on Michel Coste's website](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/Lojasiewicz.pdf) (you want section 17, "Points reguliers et dimension d’un ensemble semi-analytique").

Comment: No, I am going to check the reference. Thanks, @KReiser.